# Insert Element into multiple classes of Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

I have these class on my package:

```
1. Class Goods with attributes (name, price, id) //Goods id is unique, but the name can be the same
2. Class Storage with attributes (Goods gArray[3])
3. Class Store with attributes (name, ArrayList<Storage>) //Store name is unique
4. Class StoreSystem with attributes (ArrayList<Store>)
```

I want to insert Goods into Storage which belong to certain Store. I already succeed in inserting the Store to ArrayList, but haven't found the way to insert the Goods.

Here's the code for adding the store:

```
public String addStore(String storeName) {
    String output = "";
    if(storeCheck(storeName)) { //storeCheck used to check whether the store name exist/not.
        output = "store already exist!";
    }
    else {
        Store s1 = new Store();
        Storage st1 = new Storage();
        s1.setStoreName(storeName);
        s1.setStorageList(null);
        st1.setGArray(null);
        listOfStore.add(s1);
        listOfStorage.add(st1);
        output = "Store added";
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify whether stores are unique or not and if yes then are their unique or not

Comment: Also, is there any field using which you can uniquely identify a particular `Storage` in a `Store`? Something like a `storageId` or something?

Answer (score 1):

I believe is just this, using list as intermediate:

```
    public void addGoods(Goods g) {

        List<Goods> storageList = Arrays.asList(this.getGoods());
        storageList.add(g);
        this.setGoods(storageList.toArray());
    }
```

get and set as usual, and you will need to control the size.

Comment: From OP's description, `Storage` is not a `List` of `Goods`, but an array of fixed size 3.

Comment: I find it weird as well. But those are the requirements. Actually this is my campus assignment and that particular requirement also made me confused. Sorry.

Comment: True, fixed to array

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method in the Storage class that:

- either takes an **index** of the array and **Goods** as arguments and places the Goods in the array at that index (if you're interested in full control of where everything goes)
- or just **Goods** as argument and decides where to put them internally (if you do not care which index in the array the goods go to)

Does that make sense?

Comment: This actually make sense, I always thought I should put addGoods() method at StoreSystem class. However, if I put the addGoods() method at the Storage class, will the Storage which have those Goods be stored to the Store class as well? Or should I create another method in the StoreSystem Class to add the Storage?

Comment: I think you should keep the responsibilities of your classes clear: keep the Goods management in Storage class and the Storage management in the Store class.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `POJO` called `Storage` with the field `Goods gArray[3]`. Then have a method to add `Storage` in `Store` class (it should be as simple as using `storeArrayList.add(new Storage());` and pass 3 parameters of type Goods to it). And there you go. You have a `Storage` and `Goods` in `Storage`.

Now properly looking up for a particular `Storage` in a `Store` without assigning an index to a particular `Storage` will be a bit of a bother. Ideally, every `Storage` object should have an `id` field.

The code will look something like:
The `Store` `add` method:

```
<return-type> addToStore(Goods[] goods) {
 storageArray.add(new Storage(goods));
}
```

And then the `Storage` class will look something like:

```
class Storage {
 private final Goods gArray[3];

 public Storage(final Goods gArray) {
  this.gArray = gArray;
 }

 // getters
}
```